# Linker error IGameExplorer in Visual C++ Express Edition 2010

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, linker-errors

I want to add my game programtically to the game explorer.

In order to do this I use the [IGameExplorer interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.igameexplorer.igameexplorer%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in my code.

When i try to compile and link my code with Visual C++ 2010 Express Edition. I get the following linker error:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CLSID_GameExplorer

How do resolve this error? Is there any library to link against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Visual C++, you can try using __uuidof(GameExplorer) instead of CLSID_GameExplorer.  The GameUX.H file defines:

```
class DECLSPEC_UUID("9A5EA990-3034-4D6F-9128-01F3C61022BC")
GameExplorer;
#endif
```

which tells the C++ compiler that the CLSID for GameExplorer is `985EA990-3034-4D6F...`.